# SQLite skip a word in query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm working with SQLite (and databases in general) for the first time and I have a problem with queries.

My database contains names of streets, like Via Cesare Correnti. To allow a user to search for a street by its name I'm using this method:

```
 public List<Street> saveQueryResult(String query) throws SQLException {
    query = query.replaceAll("'", "''");

    Cursor mCursor = mDataBase.query(
            TABLE_STREETS,
            ALL_COLUMN,
            KEY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'",
            null,
            null,
            null,
            KEY_NAME + " ASC"
    );

    return createStreetsFromCursor(mCursor);
}
```

Considering for example "Via Cesare Correnti", if the users search for "Via Cesare" or "Cesare Correnti" everything works, but if he search "Via Correnti" (skipping a word) the result doesn't show up.

How can I modify my query to allow users to find streets even if they skip a word ?

Comment: can you use remote elasticsearch ? or Sqlite's FTS ? are all the street names stored on the device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> Replace white blank character by %

```
query = query.trim();
query = query.replaceAll(" ", "%");
```

Example: `"Via Correnti"` to `"%Via%Correnti%"`;
and

```
Cursor mCursor = mDataBase.query(
        TABLE_STREETS,
        ALL_COLUMN,
        KEY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        KEY_NAME + " ASC"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use full text virtual table in sqlite. This allows you to perform better matching queries against text fields. Including white space.

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE enrondata1 USING fts3(content TEXT);

And then use MATCH

See https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll take a look at fts3!